# NumberLike safely convert it back to a number

Tags: typescript, prisma, hashids

I am using Hashids, and they have the following type:

```
export declare type NumberLike = bigint | number;
```

When I try to use it on Prisma, I get an error because `id` is not a **number**

```
const id = hashids.decode(handler)
```

How can I safely convert it back to a number?

```
  const entry = await prisma.entry.findUnique({
    where: {
      id: id, // Type 'NumberLike[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)
    },
  })
```

> Type 'NumberLike[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)

Comment: If you could provide a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting as-is into a standalone IDE (like the TS Playground) then it will be easier for others to suggest an answer.  Without that I could only guess without testing.  In any case, what do you mean "safely" convert to a number?  If it's a bigint larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` then you cannot do it without losing information, which would probably be bad for a hash id.  Anyway, if you do [edit] with enough info to reproduce the issue (and/or a link to an IDE that does) and want me to take another look, mention @jcalz in a comment.

Comment: what is the type of `id`? Is it a string or bigint? How have you defined `id` in your `schema.prisma` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NumberLike can be converted into a number using the Number() function.

```
const id :number = Number(hashids.decode(hash)[0]);
```

(we use [0] to grab the first number because decode returns an array)

Or, if you encoded an array of numbers:

```
const ids :number[] = hashids.decode(hash).map(Number);
```

Answer (score 2):

As long as you haven't `hashids.encode()`-ed an array you could simply add `+` before decoding it and it will be reduced to just a number

```js
let encodedId = hashids.encode(123);
let decodedId = +hashids.decode(encodedId); // this is now of type number
```